# How can I apply different windows to one PCollection at once?

Tags: apache-beam

So my usecase is that the elements in my PCollection should be put into windows of different lengths (which are specified in the `Row` itself), but the following operations like the `GroupBy` are the same, so I don't want to split up the PCollection at this point.

So what I'm trying to do is basically this:

```py
windowed_items = (
            items
            | 'windowing' >> beam.WindowInto(window.SlidingWindows(lambda row: int(row.WINDOW_LENGTH), 60))
        )
```

However, when building the pipeline I get the error `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'`.

An alternative to applying different windows to one PCollection would be to split/branch the PCollection based on the defined window into multiple PCollections and apply the respective window to each. However, this would mean to hardcode the windowing for every allowed value, and in my case this is possibly a huge number which is why I want to avoid it.

So from the error I'm getting (but not being able to find it explicitely in the docs) I understand that the `SlidingWindows` parameters have to be provided when building the pipeline and cannot be determined at runtime. Is this correct? Is there some workaround how I can apply different windows to one PCollection at once or is it simply not possible? If that is the case, are there any other alternative approaches to the one I outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [custom session windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/custom-windows/) is what you are looking for. However, it's not supported in the Python SDK yet.

Comment: custom windows types and custom window fns are supported on dataflow runner v2. The website needs to be updated.

In this case you can implement your own window fn, example in test for reference you can find at https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9154f8b3cf01fce067cea7ad7522e1db3154ff89/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner_test.py#L1008